# Adopted first cousin - is her parent my aunt or my uncle?

Tags: dna, mitochondrial-dna

I have a first cousin who was adopted at birth. My mom had two brothers and a sister. The adoption records are sealed and cannot be viewed due to Florida state law (1969). Is it possible to determine if she is related by one of my uncles vs my aunt. Meaning is there a way to determine if the parent that is our shared match (if the sibling is my mom’s sister or brother?) is male or female?

Comment: As some further feedback I am maternal haplogroup V1a and she is V.

Answer (score 1):

A couple ways this could be solved —

If you are able to test another cousin (child of your aunt and/or uncle), this could help to rule in/out that person. If there are no cousins willing or able to test, this may not be possible.

Mitochondrial DNA would be able to verify whether it was an aunt or an uncle. Mitochondrial DNA is passed only from mother to child. As the cousin is related on your maternal line, if you shared a perfect mitochondrial match with your cousin then this would confirm she is related through your aunt. If not a match, then that would indicate it is through an uncle, because in that case your cousin would get her mitochondrial DNA from her mother, not your uncle. I don't think a haplogroup assignment is enough to confirm this, as it is very possible two people not closely related might coincidentally share the same haplogroup. The mtFull Sequence test offered by FamilyTreeDNA would probably be your best bet to compare your and your cousin's mitochondrial DNA.